# norm over differentiable functions computable from derivatives only

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

I'm running an optimization algorithm, minimizing the norm $||f-\hat f||$ of some objective function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3)$. The function $f$ cannot be computed directly, but its second derivatives with respect to all variables are easily evaluated. Currently, the strategy is to integrate $f$ twice on every iteration and use the Euclidea norm. This integration wastes a lot of time.

Can anyone suggest a useful norm for this function that would only exploit its derivatives so we don't have to integrate? The function is continuous, differentiable at least two times, and all its derivatives are bounded by known constants.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful, but you might want to have a look at some inequalities for norms of derivatives and functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs%27_inequality

Comment: What does norm mean here? Is the function $f$ vector-valued and you are minimizing the vector norm $\|f(x_{1,\ldots,6})-\hat f\|_2$, or something else?